# How to use OR operator in Freebase?

Tags: web-services, google-api, freebase

**Case:**

So, I'm using the [OR operator or ONE OF](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_operators#The_.22one_of.22_Operator_.7C.3D) as to get people from any of 2 countries.
The query looks like:

```
[{
  "id":    null,
  "type":  "/people/person",
  "/people/person/nationality": {
    "name|=": [
      "Jordan",
      "Ottoman Empire"
    ]
  },
  "name":  null,
  "limit": 30
}]
```

The query works fine, but it won't work if you increase the limit to be `40` for example. The error returned is "Unique query may have at most one result. Got 2". This means that there exist a person for both nationalities "Jordan" and "Ottoman Empire".

**Question:**

It makes sense for a "ONE OF" operator, but not for "OR" operator. Is there any operator in Freebase that can query "ANY OF" or true "OR" to cover these cases?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you used object notation ({}) which expects a single result in a place where you're returning two results and would those need an array ([]).

Having said that, I think what you really need to do is hoist your `|=` operator up a level to `/people/person/nationality`.  Note also that you need array notation even if just asking for nationality results for a person, because it's multi-valued (e.g. Sirhan Sirhan has both Jordan and Mandatory Palestine as his nationality).

Here's a query that will do what you want (although you should really use IDs for the countries rather than their English labels):

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "nationality": [],
  "type": "/people/person",
  "nationality|=": [
    "Jordan",
    "Ottoman Empire"
  ]
}]
```